# Wrong DNS Settings, php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed Name or service not known, nslookup

Tags: php, apache, dns, ping

The problem originally looked like this:

> Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: 
>       php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in 
>       /home/***/***/ppk_hotweb.class.php on line 58

I used cURL as well, it just returned null, that's it.. Both (file & cURL) were enabled.

Tried `file_get_contents('google.com')` and it worked!

Why doesn't `file_get_contents('domain.com.au')` work then?

So I started reading relevant stackoverflow posts and people say that this is a DNS settings issue.

I tried the following:

```
> # ping domain.com.au
ping: unknown host domain.com.au
```

What's wrong with the host? The site is live.

Also:

> # nslookup domain.com.au
>     Server:         203.16.60.
>
>       ***Address:        203.16.60.***#53
>
> *** Can't find domain.com.au: No answer

and

```
> # dig domain.com.au

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.10.rc1.el6_3.2 <<>> domain.com.au
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 52814
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;domain.com.au.          IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
domain.com.au.   3600    IN      SOA     ns1.web24.net.au. dns.web24.net.au. 2012080201 7200 3600 604800 3600

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 203.16.60.***#53(203.16.60.3)
;; WHEN: Sat Aug  4 05:43:23 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 92
```

I'll really appreciate any help! 
Thanks.

UPD: btw, just tried the Whois lookup...

> domain.com.au is not available

:(

Comment: The answer is to correct your `/etc/hosts`. Make sure the url points to where it should (usually localhost).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DNS server being used by your server may be using old cached DNS records since looking up that host works for me.

My `dig` results also return a valid A record which yours doesn't appear to.

This probably won't change anything given the DNS issues, but

```
file_get_contents('domain.com.au');
```

should be:

```
file_get_contents('http://domain.com.au');
```

Using the first option will try to locate a local file rather than using the `http` wrapper.

If you have permission, try changing the name servers in your `/etc/resolv.conf` file to other nameservers.

Comment: ya, i did not added http:// on quick hand.. it was there, anyway..
root@vmx***03 [/etc]# cat resolv.conf
nameserver 203.16.60.***
nameserver 203.16.61.***

it's for now..  to what IP should/can i change it?

Comment: it's from resolver settings page: " If you do not know what to put in the boxes below and cannot contact your provider, please close this window and go though this setup at a later time." 
:) i really don't know what to put there :)

Comment: Try just using Google's public DNS servers in your resolv.conf file for the time being.  Replace those nameserver lines with addresses `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` and see if you can resolve that host after that.

Comment: So i will need to change it in future?

Comment: You can safely continue using those DNS servers from Google unless your server has an explicit need to use its own nameservers for resolving certain domains under your control.  Since I don't know the full IP of the ones you were previously using, I can't say who controls them or what the deal was, but obviously they were serving stale DNS information and weren't fetching updated information as they should have.

Comment: On a debian server, with the program "resolvconf" installed, you should add the name servers to the network interface instead. Editing the resolv.conf will not work. In my case I added dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 to the eth0 stanza and solved my this error. Thanks for the help. [https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Defining_the_.28DNS.29_Nameservers]

Answer (score -2):

you can use this command without https like bellow

```
 php -r "readfile('http://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony
```