# Difference between php commandline and server

Tags: php

If I run

```
php -r 'print_r(file_get_contents("http://mirror.facebook.net/centos/timestamp.txt"));'
```

I get "Tue Oct 28 13:24:01 UTC 2014" (as expected).

But if I have a php file:

```
<?php
print_r(file_get_contents("http://mirror.facebook.net/centos/timestamp.txt"));
```

It gives me:

```
**Warning:** file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known ...

**Warning:** file_get_contents(http://mirror.facebook.net/centos/timestamp.txt): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known ...
```

What is the difference between "php -r" and php running the code out of a file

---

**UPDATE**

This is not the answer to the question but it did solve my problem so for the sake of future googlers: I don't know which of these two solutions was the key but it was working when I restarted apache.

1. In resolv.conf set `nameserver 8.8.8.8`  (which had my router's address)
2. There's an SELinux boolean `httpd_can_network_connect` which must be turned on:

> setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064372/file-get-contents-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-name-or-servi) solution and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802351/wrong-dns-settings-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-name-or-service) one.

Comment: does `nslookup mirror.facebook.net` work from the command line?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874857/php-file-get-contents-work-with-cli-but-does-not-work-when-called-on-server

Comment: @MarcB it seems to: I'm not sure what output to expect. `Server` and `Address` are my router but it then gives "Non-authoritative answer:" with mirror.facebook.net and its IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP CLI is using a different `php.ini` (or maybe no `php.ini` at all).  It's also possible you are running a completely different PHP binary than what your server is using.

You can run `php -i` on the command line, and `phpinfo()` in a script to determine which `php.ini` is in use.

Comment: My server is on my machine so surely it would be the same binary and ini file?

Comment: @j3frea Confirm it with the commands I gave you.  I have seen many cases where there are 3 or 4 copies of PHP all on the same box.  And, it's very likely you have a different config for your web server than the command line binary.  Also, don't forget that PHP can also run in many SAPIs, including Apache module which works differently than the command line binary.

Comment: I ran `php -i | grep php.ini` and got: "Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini" which is the same as `phpinfo()` gives me. I'm not sure where the binary is listed in phpinfo but I see under PHP Variables "_SERVER["PATH"] /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"